# Castle ActiveRecord, Web Project, and the Bin folder

Tags: .net, asp.net, castle-activerecord

Which assemblies are necessary to add to the Bin folder for ASP.NET 3.5 project that is going to use Castle ActiveRecord?

Is it:
Castle.ActiveRecord.dll
Castle.Core.dll
Iesi.Collections.dll
NHibernate.dll
log4net.dll

What else is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Castle RC3, you're missing Castle.DynamicProxy.dll and Castle.Components.Validator.dll

Comment: +1 and answer. Thanks. I ran into the Validator requirement late last night. I hadn't run into it needing Castle.DynamicProxy.dll yet... I wonder why. hmmm

Comment: You'll need it when you use lazy loading